# How can I loop through and pare down an object?

Tags: javascript, object

If i have the following:

```
{
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple"
},
{
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple"    
},
{
    prop: "Y",
    something: "Banana"
},
{
    prop: "Y",
    something: "Banana"
}
```

How can I morph that into a new object that would look something like this?

```
{
    prop: "X",
    apple: 2
},
{
    prop: "Y",
    banana: 2
}
```

Comment: Try using a reduce function (assuming those are arrays)

Comment: Are you having trouble coming up with an algorithm, or do you have syntax trouble?

Comment: trouble w algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single loop approach with a closure ocer a hash table for collecting the objects with the same `prop` key.

```js
var data = [{ prop: "X", something: "Apple" }, { prop: "X", something: "Apple" }, { prop: "Y", something: "Banana" }, { prop: "Y", something: "Banana" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var k2 = a.something.toLowerCase();
            if (!hash[a.prop]) {
                hash[a.prop] = { prop: a.prop };
                hash[a.prop][k2] = 0;
                r.push(hash[a.prop]);
            }
            hash[a.prop][k2]++;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With more properties to count

```js
var data = [{ prop: "X", something: "Apple", somethingElse: "Orange" }, { prop: "X", something: "Apple" }, { prop: "Y", something: "Banana" }, { prop: "Y", something: "Banana" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!hash[o.prop]) {
                hash[o.prop] = { prop: o.prop };
                r.push(hash[o.prop]);
            }
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                var k2 = o[k].toLowerCase();
                if (k !== 'prop') {
                    hash[o.prop][k2] = (hash[o.prop][k2] || 0) + 1;
                }
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is really great. How can I accomodate for a third property?

Like if I had:

    {
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple",
    somethingElse: "FruitX"
    }

Comment: please supply an example of data and the output.

Comment: Starting object: {
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple"
},
{
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple",
    somethingElse: "Orange"    
}

Result would look like: 
{
    prop: "X",
    apple: 2,
    orange: 1
}

I'm getting: {
    prop: "X",
    apple: 2,
    orange: NaN
}

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) can be helpful here:

```js
let data = [{
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple"
},
{
    prop: "X",
    something: "Apple"    
},
{
    prop: "Y",
    something: "Banana"
},
{
    prop: "Y",
    something: "Banana"
}];

let newData = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr.prop] = prev[curr.prop] || {};
  
  let lowercaseKey = curr.something.toLowerCase();
  
  
  prev[curr.prop][lowercaseKey] = prev[curr.prop][lowercaseKey] ? prev[curr.prop][lowercaseKey] + 1 : 1;
  prev[curr.prop].prop = curr.prop;

  return prev;
}, {});

newData = Object.keys(newData).map(key => newData[key]);

console.log(newData);
```

Basically, it uses an object as an accumulator (the last argument of the reduce function) to keep track of the total values for each item in the array (this is beneficial instead of just immediately pushing to a new array, because you'd first have to iterate through the new array for every iteration of the `reduce` function to find if the object already exists or not). Then, lastly, we iterate once more over all the keys of the new object, and get the values.

Pro-tip: Easier to understand if you play around with the code snippet above and log the values during each iteration.